# Windows Shell Script - Closing the command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I assume this is pretty easy so here goes; I'm trying to execute these commands and then close the command prompt after Firefox opens.  How do I do that?  I can't get back to a command prompt after "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4>null" (i'm simulating a sleep here).

```
@echo off
call tskill firefox
call ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4>nul
call C:\"Program Files"\"Mozilla Firefox 3"\firefox
call exit
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'start' to start the process separately.  For instance:

```
@echo off
ping 127.0.0.1
start IEXPLORE.EXE "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

I used IEXPLORE because I didn't want to look up the path to firefox.  Adjust for your preferences.

Answer (score 3):

actually if you just do:

```
@echo off
call ping 127.0.0.1
start http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

the url will open in your default web browser. surrounding the url with quotes seems to mess it up.

-don